# Plotly plot background for subplots isn't updating

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm trying to edit the background for the subplots (to make it white), but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my code:

```
fig1.update_layout(
    template="plotly_white")
```

Here's the plot: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ9cn.png)

It also crops the blue background sometimes :/ [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kboRc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the background color, you can do the following:

```
fig1.update_layout(
 margin=dict(l=10, r=10, t=45, b=10),
 paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
 plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
)
```

Use the `bgcolor` for backgrounds and `margin` for the cropping out part. You may need to play around with the values to get the right look and feel for your specific application.